# In a git or github repository is there a way to notify or set a status that you are working on an issue?

Tags: git, github

I know you can assign an issue to a specific person but is there a way to define in git or github that you are working on a specific issue?

Comment: This has nothing to do with git. This is about issue tracking app. Github does have its own issue tracking feature. In it and similar software you can set lists like (TODO, Doing, Done etc) to track the status of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to differentiate between git and GitHub here.

Git is just a version control system with no concept of "issues" or "tickets".

GitHub is an online service where you can host your git-based repositories and GitHub happens to include an issue tracker called "GitHub Issues".
But you could also use a different issue tracker, like Jira or Bugzilla.

In GitHub Issues (and most other issue tracking systems) there is the concept of an "assignee" which you can use to track who is working on what.

Comment: And you can make whatever labels you want, including "in progress" or whatever.